# Comment form not working? (Ruby on Rails) undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, methods, comments

Hello helpful kind souls.

I am getting the 'undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass' error when I try to submit a new comment.
It highlights this part of the user controller :

```
def create
    @comment = @user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
```

My comments controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @comment = @user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

   if @comment.save
      redirect_to users_show_path, notice: 'Comment submitted!'
    else
      render 'users/show'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
  end

 def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :username)
  end

end
```

My user model includes has_many :comments and my comments model has  belongs_to :user

Where do I need to look to correct this error? Thanks!

Comment: A little bit of searching will go a long way ..

Answer (score 1):

Well, where you have defined the value `@user` ? as I am seeing you didn't, In Ruby, if you use **instance variables** before defining them, they will simply give you `nil` object in return. Finally, you are calling the association method `comments` on the `nil` object. That's why the exception you got.

So, set the `@user` to an `User` instance first then call `comments` on it.

Comment: isn't @user defined in the user controller? where else would i put it? i  am new to this :x thanks for responding kind one

Comment: @icecreamrabbit Humm.  You can put it inside the method where you are using it.. But there are several ways to do that.

Comment: @icecreamrabbit have a quick look into this -- [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-articles)